# How to run a .NET Core Web App on Apache without Core Runtime?

Tags: apache, .net-core, publish

I developed a web application in .NET Core in VS 2017 for Windows. I published it on Linux Mint using the independent mode (Self-contained deployment). How to run it on Apache without installing .Net Core runtime?

With Console App (Self-contained deployment) it's possible with this Linux command ./DllName.

Comment: If it's anything like nginx, you'd set up Apache as a proxy

Comment: Not need to set proxy, core runtime in not installed (dotnet command don't exist) so it's not start on port 5000, all files are in virtual apache folder

Comment: self-contained means the runtime is in there.  (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore21) It's likely you'll want to invoke that

Comment: Right self-contained means the runtime is in there, but not work on apache, I can't run website, I see only file list in the folder from web browser.

Comment: Have you tried this without installing the runtime?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: On the link : prerequisite --> Install the .NET Core runtime on the server.

Comment: The official apache guide assumes you use Framework Dependent Deployment. To tailor that guide for Self-Contained Deployment, 1) you don't need the .NET Core runtime any more. 2) any reference to `dotnet` commands, should be replaced with your own executable (generated on Windows via `dotnet publish` and match your project name). I suggest you follow the guide to learn FDD first, and then switch to SCD when you fully understand all the concepts.

Comment: FDD = You Need Runtime Installed on server Machine SCD = You not Need Runtime installed on server Machine. I have developed Console Application in FDD and to run it on linux you have to install Runtime. Same console application in SCD not need runtime installed just call ./appName. so the question is how to run web application in SCD with Apache?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, the error was caused by a Visual Studio bug that generated dll in the wizard but was corrupted. publishing the application via cmd works.

Comment: You should accept your own answer to close the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

In publish screen edit setting to self-contained

[image: profile settings]